# Generate a list of 24 entries and check if content is present in object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, for-loop

I need to generate a calendar day overview with **24** list entries - 1 per hour. How to combine `v-for="(product, index) in products"` and checking `product.name.startTimeHour` for every hour **0-23**?

What I have so far:

```
  <template  v-for="(product, index) in products">

    <product-item
      v-if="product.name.startTimeHour === '11'"
      :key="product.id"
      :index="index"
      :data="product"
    ></product-item>
    <template v-else>
    No entry for startTimeHour: [time]  
    </template>  

</template>
```

(I'm using the [Bento VueJS starter](https://github.com/kefranabg/bento-starter/blob/master/src/components/ProductList.vue) template for this if relevant)

Comment: So, you have 24 products?

Comment: @lucas the amount of products changes constantly. That is kind the issue - e.g. how to generate 24 entries if there are only 4 products?

Comment: This really needs more info to properly answer, such as the format of the data and more explanation on desired result. And a more robust "what have you tried".

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/vdxtwsre/).

Used markup:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="hourNumber in 24" class="hour-entry">
    <div
      class="product"
      v-for="(product, idx) in products"
      v-if="product.startTimeHour === hourNumber"
      key="product.id"
    >
      {{ product.name }}
    </div>
    <div v-if="getProductsNumPerHour(hourNumber) === 0">
      No entry for startTimeHour [{{ hourNumber }}]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Used JS:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

  data: {
    products: [
        {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Product One',
        startTimeHour: 4
      },
       {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Product Two',
        startTimeHour: 10
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Product Three',
        startTimeHour: 15
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Product Four',
        startTimeHour: 15
      },
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    getProductsNumPerHour (hourNum) {
        return this.products.filter(prod => {
        return prod.startTimeHour === hourNum
      }).length
    }
  }
})
```

Here we iterate through 24 hours numbers number first, then through all existing products inside each hour number and render only products which start time hour matches with current time hour number.

And there is aux method `getProductsNumPerHour()` for detecting when we have no products for a given hour number at all.

I was not sure about your code `product.name.startTimeHour`, it looks like your product **name** property is an object, but why not to place **startTimeHour** as separate product property as in my example. If I'm missing something, please explain your needs more detailed.